# IPMI View Display Hangs Installing CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos6, ipmi

I have a CentOS 6.5 iso image that I've attached to IPMI View via Virtual Media. I'm in the KVM console. I boot the system. I select "Install or Upgrade." I next select "Skip Media Test." I then get the CentOS banner but it never goes past that. I've not had trouble installing CentOS 5 from an iso image and IPMI View.

Is this a known problem? Should I run the media test? Could this be an IPMI View problem?

Comment: Am checking the media to cover all bases.

Comment: What is the hardware?

Comment: Media test succeeded. Hardware is Supermicro - 6026TT-HTRF (4 Hot-swap nodes).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this was pilot error. The UI combined with my small laptop display has taken some getting used to and I didn't notice that I had to scroll down a ways to see the "Next" button. Hopefully, someone will benefit from my mistake.